# how to handle synchronous databse query in node.js

Tags: node.js, async.js

I am new to node.js, and I am starting with login and signUp implementation, and I have just found that my database Query of MySQL failed to execute in sequence. So what I do is to find does username match exisiting usernames in database, and invitation codes, if there exist, I will send my JSON file with property true, otherwise false, but I have just found, the json file is sent before the database query is finished, so that even if user name matched, the response property is still set to false. I tried async and sync but I still have trouble understanding and fixing my error, can someone please help me on fix or a better alternative implementation in this case? Thank you!!

Here is my code:

```
// build up connection to db
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'pwd',
  database: 'test'
});

// async function search

async function dbFind(db, dbName, attribute, value) {
  let users;
  try{
    console.log(`11111111111111`)
    const users = await db.promise().query(`SELECT EMAIL_ADRESS FROM ${dbName} WHERE ${attribute} = ?`, [value]);
    // console.log(`users: ${users}`)
    if (users) {
        return users;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
  } catch (err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}


// parse the json file from front-end and save it in variable data 
app.post('/API/user/registration', function(req,res){
con.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
});

var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;
var invicode = req.body.invitation_code;
var name = req.body.name;
console.log('reqeust ' + req.body)

// variable initialization
var invitationCodeMatched = false;
var role = 'student';
const uid = uuid.v4();
var verifyToken = uuid.v1()
var flag = true;


// // check if the username have already been registered  isRegistered

if (dbFind.sync(con, 'login_Authentication', 'EMAIL_ADRESS', username) != null){
    flag = false
} else {
    flag = true
}
console.log(`1 ${flag}`)

// check invitation code to see if a user qualify for a TA:
if (dbFind(con, 'invitation_code', 'INVITATION_CODE', invicode) != null){
    role = 'TA';
    invitationCodeMatched = true
}
console.log(`3 ${invitationCodeMatched}`)

  // otherwisr: insert it into te database:
  const uLoginAuth = {
    USER_ID: uid,
    EMAIL_ADRESS: username, 
    PSWORD:password,
    VERIFIED: false,
    VERIFYCODE: verifyToken
  };

  const uInfo = {
    USER_ID: uid, 
    NME: name, 
    USER_ROLE: role,
    EMAIL_ADRESS: username
  };

  if(flag){
    con.query('INSERT INTO login_authentication SET ?', uLoginAuth, (err, res) => {
        if(err) throw err;
      
        console.log('Last insert ID:', res.insertId);
      });

    con.query('INSERT INTO user_info SET ?', uInfo, (err, res) => {
        if(err) throw err;

        console.log('Last insert ID:', res.insertId);
    });
  }

con.query('SELECT * FROM user_info', (err,rows) => {
    if(err) throw err;
  
    console.log('Data received from Db:');
    console.log(rows);
});

con.end((err) => {
// The connection is terminated gracefully
// Ensures all remaining queries are executed
// Then sends a quit packet to the MySQL server.
});
//send json file to the front end

console.log(`2 ${flag}`)

let judge = { 
    isRegistered: flag,
    invitationCodeMatched: invitationCodeMatched
};
res.json(judge);
//If the user has not yet verified:
lib.sendConfirmationEmail(name, username, verifyToken)
});

app.listen(3000)
```

The output while hearing from request is:

```
1 false
2 false
```

and there is no output of 11111111 inside async dbFind function, there is a database match in this scenario, but what it returns is :

```
{
  "isRegistered": false,
  "invitationCodeMatched": false
}
```

which is the default value that is initailized before.

Comment: What is `dbFind.sync()`.  The function you show is `dbFind()` and because it is `async`, it returns a promise which you would need to `await` or use `.then()` to get its value.

Comment: In addition, `db.promise().query()` doesn't look correct.  What database module from NPM are you using?

Comment: Your `con.connect()` isn't correct either as that's a non-blocking API call so you have to proceed with the connection from within the callback (or use a promise interface and await that promise).  In fact, pretty much all the programming with asynchronous calls here is wrong.

Comment: I am using MySQL as my database module, I just learned in from the tutorial, how could I improve this in this case? I know I messed up

Comment: Which exact module on NPM are you using for mysql as there are several different ones?  Some support promises, so do not.  Please provide the exact link to it on NPM.